# Does pf sense support mips architecture?

Tags: cross-compiling, freebsd, mips64, pfsense

if so then how to cross compile it from src using build.sh script given at pf sense GitHub repository
Any link to a related (cross compile pfsense for MIPS) documentation would be helpful

Answer (score -1):

pfsense only supports amd64 and i386 (older versions).

The FreeBSD wiki contains some Information how to cross compile for MIPS https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/BuildingMIPS